# TypeError: $("#view_map").fancybox is not a function

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm getting the following error in Firebug for one of my pages...

```
TypeError: $("#view_map").fancybox is not a function
    'overlayColor': '#333'
```

Here's the code that's throwing it...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#view_map').fancybox({
                'autoDimensions': false,
                'width': 750,
                'height': 550,
                'padding': 0,
                'easingIn': 'swing',
                'easingOut': 'swing',
                'overlayOpacity': 0.75,
                'overlayColor': '#333'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Regardless of what the last option is in the function, it puts that option in the error. Is there a syntax error in there or something? I can see anything wrong with it.

EDIT:

Here's the call to the scripts...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.triadbarspecials.com/fancybox/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
```

(The easing pack is 1.3.4; at some point I accidentally removed the .4 from the name. IDK why)

Here's the anchor with the ID referenced in the function...

```
<a id="view_map" href="#map" style="color: #fcb60e; text-decoration: none;">View Map</a>
```

## map is the div that contains a map, which is what my fancybox is all about

Comment: Have you got the definition of `$.fn.fancybox()` available to your script?

Comment: Are you including the necessary script file..

Comment: try loading jQuery and fancybox (in that order) before your custom script. Also check that the `<a id="view_map" />` tag (or other tag with the same ID) exists.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect what y'all asked about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my original post on this I have removed fancybox from my site. Never figured out a solution, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You're not loading the fancybox script, you're loading jQuery and the easing script (which smooths animations).

Put a call to your fancybox script before the easing script.

*`Edit: Dont forget the CSS file either.`*

Comment: that's it ... it's easing js version's fault, which looks alike ;)

Comment: Cool! Glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: don't say "victory" yet, I am not the OP ;)

Comment: oh, haha. Was gun hoe for a second. Living vicariously through people.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the script for the fancybox function? eg

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
```

(As pointed out below, change the path and file name to reflect your file structure and fancybox version.)

Comment: I am afraid that the OP is using v1.3.4 so this answer could be a little bit misleading

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, after i upgrade my jquery to 1.10.

So i downgraded my jquery to 1.8 and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

if you use new version of jQuery you have to add jQuery migrate plugin http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js